# computational time and precision trade off

Tags: data-mining, bigdata

I know that there are a number of predictive models (generized linear ones, trees, neural network, support vector machines, knn, Naive Bayes, ...) that have been proposed to perform various analytical tasks. Now I am striving to find appropriate references about their performance when the data becames "Big". In other words, how is their performance when the data becames really big. Does the training time increase more than linear? Is there any comparative benchmark between computational time and precision when the data becames high (for the various predictive models).

Comment: The answer will depend on whether you want to parallelize using approximate versions of algorithms or not (and how you would want to parallelize them, example multicore or multinode). On a single machine, without any parallel processing, the complexity can be fairly well tracked.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, as it doesn't answer your question. Why don't you perform a search on the Internet? I'm sure that a proper comprehensive search will result in significant number (likely, hundreds) of relevant papers.

Answer (score -1):

A good reference can be found there http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/